# Webpack with Babel not working in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to configure my react app using webpack and babel.
I have created webpack.config.js which looks like this:

```
> var webpack = require("webpack"); var path = require("path"); var
> HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"); const VENDORLIBS =
> ["react", "react-dom"]; module.exports = {   mode: 'development',  
> entry: {
>     bundle: "./src/index.js",
>     vendor: VENDORLIBS   },   output: {
>     path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
>     filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"   },   devtool:'inline-source-map',   module: {
>     rules: [
>       {
>         test: /\.js$/,
>         use: "babel-loader",
>         exclude: /node_modules/
>       },
>       {
>         test: /\.css$/,
>         use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
>       },
>       {
>         test: /\.scss$/,
>         use: "sass-loader"
>       }
>     ]   },   plugins: [
>     new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
>       names: ["vendor", "manifest"]
>     }),
>     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
>       template: "public/index.html"
>     })   ] };
```

I have also created .babelrc which looks like:

```
   {
    "presets": [
       "babel-preset-env",
        "react"
    ]
}
```

Now, when I run this using webpack, I got an error which looks like:

>

```
 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! eccomerce@1.0.0 test-build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the eccomerce@1.0.0 test-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Please help me out of this problem as I am stuck badly.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I think your webpack entry: {} could be causing the issue.

Replace it with `entry: './src/index.js'`

And make sure you have all your babel requirements installed:

@babel/core
@babel/preset-env
babel-loader

And refer to the [Webpack Docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)

Comment: I made my entry as suggested, but it did not help. Error still persists.

Comment: The same configuration is working fine on Linux, but I am using cygwin on windows, and getting an error.